# How to pass php array to Google JavaScript Map API make label?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

Here is the code, I do get the longitude and latitude from the database, but now cannot writer to Google Javascript Maps API to make red circle on the map. I think there is some problems on Js object.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        die("<center>Sorry, please check your network connection!</center>");
    }

    $longiArray = array();
    $latitArray = array();
    $num        = 0;

    $longitude = $db->query("SELECT * FROM water");
    $longitude->num_rows;

    while ($row = $longitude->fetch_object()) {
        $longiArray[$num] = $row->longi;
        $latitArray[$num] = $row->latit;
        $num++;
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title>
                        Circles
                    </title>
                    <style>
                        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
                    </style>
                </meta>
            </meta>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="map">
            </div>
            <script>

    var city = new Array();
    var counter = <?php echo"$num";?>;
    for (var x = 0; var x < counter; var x++){
      var citymap = {
        city[x] = {
          center: {lat: <?php echo"$latitArray[x]";?>, 
          lng: <?php echo"$longiArray[x]";?>},
          population: 10
        },
      }
    };

    function initMap() {
      // Create the map.
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {lat: -28.73226, lng: 24.76232},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      });

     for (var city in citymap) {

       var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
      });
    }



    }
            </script>
            <script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Google API Key here &signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I make some change of the code from Map API site. Now cannot work - -。

Comment: What does the HTML/javascript generated by the PHP look like?

Comment: It didn't generate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of corrections:

1. Meta tags are self-closing, so they don't need a `</meta>`. Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML) for more information.
2. Get a key for your google maps - refer to the [Google Maps documentation for this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

   So this: `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
   type="text/javascript"></script>` 
   should become something like: 
    `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=asdf23f2...23f&callback=initMap"
   type="text/javascript"></script>`
3. Generate the citymap javascript variable using PHP and [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) see example below. Does each database record have a `name` column? We need to have a label for each city (e.g. 'chicago', 'vancouver' etc), in order to have a key for each city:

```php
$longitude = $db->query("SELECT * FROM water");
//$longitude->num_rows;//what is the point of this line?
$cityMap = array();
while ($row = $longitude->fetch_object()) {
  //presuming we have a name column - otherwise assign from another source (e.g. array of cities)
  $cityMap[$row->name] = array(
    'center' => array(
      'lng' => $row->longi,
      'lat' => $row->latit
    ),
    'population' => 10
  );
?>
<!-- in the html body .... -->

<script>

var citymap = <? echo json_encode($cityMap); ?>;

function initMap() {
```

Comment: 1) Thanks, get it.  2) I do have it, I remove the KEY when post this question.   3) It does have a column with name of city (in db is called "city"), so does the name of city must be differ every time? (in the db, it's same city). In the json_encode($cityMap), $cityMap it's array in php, does it encode entire php array to Js array?

Comment: I did make change, but still not generate Google Map.        <?php
error_reporting(0);
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die("<center>Sorry, please check your network connection!</center>");
}

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM water");
$select->num_rows;
$cityMap = array();

while ($row = $select->fetch_object()) {
    $cityMap[$row->city] = array(
        'center'     => array(
            'lng' => $row->longi,
            'lat' => $row->latit,
        ),
        'population' => 10,
    );
}
?>

Comment: Yes the array keys must be unique - per [php.net](http://php.net/array): `If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.` so you could append the value of `num` to each city: e.g `$citymap[$row->city.$num++] = array('center'...` -does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info. Then I think there is something went wrong with Js code, it didn't generates the map - which I think the "citymap" (Js object) didn't support Array...

Comment: I found there is a way to do it, but is very old: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#createtable

Comment: Hmm if you inspect in your browser console, in the **Elements** tab (at least in Chrome) can you see the `<script>` tag with the var city map? does it look like the same formatting as this: `var citymap = {"vancouver":{"population":10,"center":{"lat":49.25,"lng":-123.1}},"chicago":{"population":10,"center":{"lat":41.878,"lng":-87.629}}};

    function initMap() {` ?

Comment: Look at [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4ixz-6hd0)  where I simulate making the array in the while loop and output the json_encoded array (as html instead of in a script tag but it should be identical). Does your array output look identical to that?

Comment: Yes, my output does look like that, but I don't think the Google Js Maps API supports the Js Array object. When I try to generate the map, it dose nothing.

Answer (score 0):

error is from cityArray in javascript. correct like bellow:

```
<?php 
echo "var city = new Array();";
echo "var counter = $num";
for($x=0 ; $x<$num ; $x++){
      echo "var citymap = {".
        "city[x] = {".
          "center: {lat: $latitArray[$x] ,". 
          "lng: $longiArray[$x] }, ".
          "population: 10".
        "},".
      "}";
}
?>
```

Comment: That will lead to `var citymap` being redeclared per each iteration, so it will only contain the last values from the latitude and longitude arrays...also `x`  in `city[x]` won't have a value, since there is no `var x` before that...

Comment: Hmmmm... I did try, but didn't generate anything.